# it's possible modify styles from AD FS en Windows Server 2012 R2 login page?

Tags: windows, authentication, adfs3.0

we are working in customizing login page from AD FS en Windows Server 2012 R2

Changes work correctly in a local navigator, but when load changes to server, we don't see any image and some fonts fail too.

It's just to know if anyone has really make a great change in login page only changes CSS file.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/change-the-company-logo-on-the-ad-fs-sign-in-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a whole lot of tips and tricks described at [ADFS : Continuing the Login and Home Realm Discovery (HRD) and Change Password customisation adventure](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2017/06/adfs-continuing-login-and-home-realm.html).

The css specific reference is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/custom-web-themes-in-ad-fs).